# Edelstein's fixed point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I just read that Edelstein fixed point theorem did not assume compactness in his original proof of his fixed point theorem for contractive mappings, but rather the existence of a point $a \in X$ whose
sequence of iterates $x_n=f_n(a)$ has a convergent subsequence. What would the proof look like?

Comment: May be interesting to you https://fixedpointtheoryandapplications.springeropen.com/track/pdf/10.1186/1687-1812-2012-107

Comment: @MathOverview The article sadly doesn't provide a proof of Edelsteins theorem

Comment: @antoni Did you look up the original paper? If not, do you have a reference?

Comment: @max_zorn yes I eventually found the original paper with the mentioned proof: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-37.1.74